# undefined index error when submitting form and inserting values into database?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following HTML form:

```
<form name="request" action="include/process_ns_request.php" onsubmit="return ValidateNewSupplierRequest()" method="POST">

<input type="text" id="comp_name" placeholder="Company Name" class="login_form2"/>

<select class="login_form2_select" id="comp_type">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Company Type</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>  


<input type="text" id="comp_reg" placeholder="Company Reg. Number" class="login_form2" />

<select class="login_form2_select" disabled id="address">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Address Line</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>


<input type="text" id="vat_numb" placeholder="Company VAT Number" class="login_form2" />

<input type="text" id="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" class="login_form2" />

<input type="text" id="cont_name" placeholder="Contact Name" class="login_form2" />

<input type="text" id="cont_email" placeholder="Contact Email" class="login_form2" />



<input type="text" id="cont_tel" placeholder="Contact Tel. Number" class="login_form2" />

<input type="text" id="conf_email" placeholder="Confirm Contact Email" class="login_form2" />



<input type="text" id="cont_mob" placeholder="Mobile Number (Optional)" class="login_form2" />

<input type="text" id="promo" placeholder="Promotional Code" class="login_form2" />


<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

i am then posting my form data to my mysql query page: process_ns_request.php

```
 <?php 
    session_start();
    include("config.php");

    if (isset($_POST['request'])) {
    // do stuff
    //retrieve our data from POST
    $comp_name = $_POST['comp_name'];
    $comp_reg = $_POST['comp_reg'];
    $comp_type = $_POST['comp_type'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $vat_numb = $_POST['vat_numb'];
    $cont_name = $_POST['cont_name'];
    $cont_email = $_POST['cont_email'];
    $conf_email = $_POST['conf_email'];
    $cont_tel = $_POST['cont_tel'];  
    $cont_mob = $_POST['cont_mob'];



    $comp_name = stripslashes($comp_name);
    $comp_name = mysql_real_escape_string($comp_name);
    $comp_reg = stripslashes($comp_reg);
    $comp_reg = mysql_real_escape_string($comp_reg);
    $comp_type = stripslashes($comp_type);
    $comp_type = mysql_real_escape_string($comp_type);
    $address = stripslashes($address);
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($address);
    $postcode = stripslashes($postcode);
    $postcode = mysql_real_escape_string($postcode);
    $vat_numb = stripslashes($vat_numb);
    $vat_numb = mysql_real_escape_string($vat_numb);
    $cont_name = stripslashes($cont_name);
    $cont_name = mysql_real_escape_string($cont_name);
    $cont_email = stripslashes($cont_email);
    $cont_email = mysql_real_escape_string($cont_email);
    $conf_email = stripslashes($conf_email);
    $conf_email = mysql_real_escape_string($conf_email);
    $cont_tel = stripslashes($cont_tel);
    $cont_tel = mysql_real_escape_string($cont_tel);
    $cont_mob = stripslashes($cont_mob);
    $cont_mob = mysql_real_escape_string($cont_mob);


    }else{
        echo 'form was not submitted';
    }



    $query = "INSERT INTO new_supplier_request (id, reference, user_id, date, status, payment_term) VALUES ('', '123','2', now(), 'Pending', '$comp_name')";
    echo 'ok';
    ?>
```

However, I get an index undefined error for all my variables. can someone please show me what i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: You must add 'name' attribute to all your input fields. Php can't get 'id' value... But, since you have tagged ajax... could you show us your ajax request code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and how can php get the posted value without the name attribute :

```
<input type="text" name="comp_name" id="comp_name" placeholder="Company Name" class="login_form2"/>
```

add name to all input